# MotionLayout and data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-motionlayout

I've a button inside a MotionLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@{DEBUG ? 40dp : 16dp}"
            android:paddingStart="34dp"
            android:paddingEnd="34dp"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:enabled="false" />
```

and a ConstraintSet for this button:

```
<Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@{DEBUG ? 40dp : 16dp}"
            android:paddingStart="34dp"
            android:paddingEnd="34dp"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:enabled="false"
            app:debugMarginBottom="@{@dimen/gap_40_dp}"
            app:marginBottom="@{@dimen/gap_16_dp}"
           >
```

while `app:debugMarginBottom` and `app:marginBottom` are bindingAdapter values I created.

The problem is that the compilation fails cause app:debugMarginBottom is unknown (but if i put it in the layout itself, everything works).

How can I use data binding with MotionLayout?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to declare [custom attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout#custom_attributes) as children of your `Constraint`.

Comment: @Pawel doesn't work for me, do you have an example, to make sure i'm doing it right?

Comment: sorry that was only a tip for constraintset complaining about unknown attributes, but I'm  pretty sure databinding won't hook into MotionScene properly.

Comment: DataBinding is a function of Layout. 
Constraint only contains ConstraintSet (It is not a layout)
So..
style, android:paddingStart, android:paddingEnd, android:text, android:textAlignment, tools:enabled, app:debugMarginBottom. 

Are not attributes of Constraint

Answer (score 0):

In General ConstraintSet / Constraint are not rec/layout files. They do not contain all the tags of layout. They contain tags for ConstraintLayout and View Transforms.
When used in MotionLayout They also can contain special motionLayout related tags.

For details on tags in Constraint see [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout#constraint).

They are superficially similar so that we do not have two different words for the same thing. (e.g. margin_top)